# How can I stop remix from appending ?index on my URL?

Tags: remix, remix.run

On my UI, I have a list of items on a page. I want the user to be able to hit a thumbs up image to "like" the item.

I have implemented this by having a form that passes the item id to a remix action handler. That works fine and I can record the "like" on my database. The problem I have is that the url gets changed to ?index.

I have read this https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/routing#what-is-the-index-query-param but I want to stop this behaviour.

Example:

User is on
mysite.com/houses

and then clicks like on a house that is shown to them.

The URL changes to mysite.com/houses?index

I want the URL to be unchanged on the "like" action.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using

```
const fetcher = useFetcher();
```

and `<fetcher.Form></fetcher.Form>` in place of `<Form></Form>`

Docs: https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/remix#usefetcher

> sometimes you want to call a loader outside of navigation, or call an action (and get the routes to reload) but you don't want the URL to change. Many interactions with the server aren't navigation events. This hook lets you plug your UI into your actions and loaders without navigating.